# MongoDB parallel updates to a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am kind of new to MongoDB have this question, Say I have a product collection, `

```
{
  _id: 100,
  sku: "abc123",
  quantity: 250,
  instock: true,
  reorder: false,
  details: { model: "14Q2", make: "xyz" },
  tags: [ "apparel", "clothing" ],
  ratings: [ { by: "ijk", rating: 4 } ]
}
```

`

I would like to update this product collection concurrently with two update statement in different threads, Thread1, `

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set:
      {
        quantity: 500,
        details: { model: "14Q3"}
      }
   }
)
```

`Thread 2,`

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set: { "details.make": "zzz" } }
)
```

`

As the two threads happens concurrently in same document,just wanted to know irrespective of the order it happens  the output is `{ "_id" : 100, "sku" : "abc123", "quantity" : 500, "instock" : true, "reorder" : false, "details" : { "model" : "14Q3", "make" : "zzz" }, "tags" : [ "apparel", "clothing" ], "ratings" : [ { "by" : "ijk", "rating" : 4 } ] }`  This type of atomic behaviour in a single document is supported by Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single document updates in MongoDB are [atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity), but because you're not using dot-notation in your "Thread 1" update, if that update happens second, the entire `details` subdocument will be overwritten to `{ model: "14Q3"}`.

However, if you change that update to use dot-notation, then the update order is irrelevant:

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set:
      {
        quantity: 500,
        "details.model": "14Q3"
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Good to know this,Much appreciated.